# Magento Fedex not working for UK country

Tags: magento-1.9, fedex

I am facing one issue, FedEx shipping method is not working for UK country in Magento 1.9.0.1 with sandbox detail.

I am getting following Exception log,

```
2015-07-10T10:03:18+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [request] => Array
        (
            [WebAuthenticationDetail] => Array
                (
                    [UserCredential] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => tFcgROSGu9EWhxUK
                            [Password] => 25oe26KMO0ODzSLLVaLhGogFE
                        )

                )

            [ClientDetail] => Array
                (
                    [AccountNumber] => 510087623
                    [MeterNumber] => 118674309
                )

            [Version] => Array
                (
                    [ServiceId] => crs
                    [Major] => 10
                    [Intermediate] => 0
                    [Minor] => 0
                )

            [RequestedShipment] => Array
                (
                    [DropoffType] => REGULAR_PICKUP
                    [ShipTimestamp] => 2015-07-10T10:03:14+00:00
                    [PackagingType] => YOUR_PACKAGING
                    [TotalInsuredValue] => Array
                        (
                            [Amount] => 128.38
                            [Currency] => UKL
                        )

                    [Shipper] => Array
                        (
                            [Address] => Array
                                (
                                    [PostalCode] => M8 8JJ
                                    [CountryCode] => GB
                                )

                        )

                    [Recipient] => Array
                        (
                            [Address] => Array
                                (
                                    [PostalCode] => B3 2EW
                                    [CountryCode] => GB
                                    [Residential] => 
                                )

                        )

                    [ShippingChargesPayment] => Array
                        (
                            [PaymentType] => SENDER
                            [Payor] => Array
                                (
                                    [AccountNumber] => 510087623
                                    [CountryCode] => GB
                                )

                        )

                    [CustomsClearanceDetail] => Array
                        (
                            [CustomsValue] => Array
                                (
                                    [Amount] => 128.38
                                    [Currency] => UKL
                                )

                        )

                    [RateRequestTypes] => LIST
                    [PackageCount] => 1
                    [PackageDetail] => INDIVIDUAL_PACKAGES
                    [RequestedPackageLineItems] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [Weight] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Value] => 1
                                            [Units] => LB
                                        )

                                    [GroupPackageCount] => 1
                                )

                        )

                    [ServiceType] => SMART_POST
                    [SmartPostDetail] => Array
                        (
                            [Indicia] => PARCEL_SELECT
                            [HubId] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [result] => stdClass Object
        (
            [HighestSeverity] => ERROR
            [Notifications] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Severity] => ERROR
                    [Source] => crs
                    [Code] => 712
                    [Message] => Destination country is not serviced. 
                    [LocalizedMessage] => Destination country is not serviced. 
                )

            [Version] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ServiceId] => crs
                    [Major] => 10
                    [Intermediate] => 0
                    [Minor] => 0
                )

        )

    [__pid] => 8116
)
```

can anybody knows why FedEx shipping methods not showing in checkout when I am using UK address.

Sample address which I am using

```
Unit 14
3 Edgar Buildings
George Street
Bath
England
BA1 2FJ
```